# Form with setLayout and displayFieldError not working, workaround?

Tags: atk4

i have a code like this:

```
$f = $this->add('Form', null, null, array('form/stacked'));         
$f->setModel('Application',false);
$f->setLayout('form/create_brand_2');
$f_fbid = $f->addField('Line','app_id','')->validateNotNull();

if($f->isSubmitted()){
  return $f_fbid->displayFieldError('Error text');
}
```

But i get no error text, neither on validateNotNull. It is working without setting layout. Is this a bug or it just the way it is, what would be the best workouround?

Comment: Is it ATK 4.3 version or 4.2 ?

Comment: uh, sorry, 4.3 afcourse...

Comment: I'm not good at 4.3. I'm still using 4.2 :) So I hope someone else will find time to answer your question sometime soon.